# Material UI Tree View, check if the node i click has children

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

so im trying to create a tree using the Tree View from Material UI ( https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/). We can take the example from their page:

```
const data = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 110,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function RecursiveTreeView() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={['root']}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      {renderTree(data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

What i want to do, is that whenever i click on a node, to fire some function only if its a leaf node. The "onNodeSelect" props that the treeview has only gives me the node id but not any other information about the node. I know one aproach is to search the original json for that id and find the node and  then check if it has childrens, but my json is quite large and i would like not to do that. Any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use the onLabelClick of the TreeItem component and ditch the "selection" part of the treeview (e.g. use disableSelection on the TreeView).

Then your code could become

```
const handleTreeItemClick = (node) => {
  if( node.children && node.children.length ) {
    // do some stuff
  } else {
    // do something else
  }  
}

const renderTree = (nodes) => (
  <TreeItem
    key={nodes.id}
    nodeId={nodes.id}
    label={nodes.name}
    onLabelClick={() => handleTreeItemClick(nodes)}
  >
    {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
  </TreeItem>
);
```

Otherwise you might be able to make a hash of the data with ids pointing to the data node (not sure of performance hashing a large json object?), then just lookup the value from the hash rather than searching every time. Annoying I know e.g.

```
// do this outside of the render, perhaps in a redux selector or reducer
const hashMethod = (nodes, hash = {}) => {
  return nodes.reduce((h, node) => {
    h[node.id] = node;
    if( node.children) {
      h = hashMethod(node.children, h);
    }  
    return h;
  }, hash);
}

// sorry turned it into an array first so I can use reduce easier
const hashedData = hashMethod([data]);
```

Then in an onNodeSelect handler within the component (for a single select)

```
const handleNodeSelect = (nodeId) => {
  const node = hashedData(nodeId);
  // do what you need with the data
}
```